# PLS -00103 Error Stored Procedure Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I tried compiling the following procedure and got PLS-00103 error.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getFlightDetails
(ticketNumberIn IN integer, fullName OUT varchar2(60), flightNumberOut OUT integer, 
 route OUT varchar2(50), durationInHours OUT number(6,4)) 
IS
BEGIN
  select    
    pe.FirstName || ' ' || pe.LastName into fullName,
    fl.FlightNumber into flightNumberOut,
    fl.DepartureAirport || ' - ' || fl.ArrivalAirport into route,
    ROUND((fl.ArrivalDate - fl.DepartureDate)*24,1) into durationInHours
  from Purchase pu
    inner join Person pe on pe.SSN = pu.SSN
    inner join Ticket ti on ti.TicketNumber = pu.TicketNumber
    inner join Flight fl on fl.FlightNumber = ti.FlightNumber
  where pu.TicketNumber = ticketNumberIn;
END;
```

What have I done wrong? I mean, I already searched the Error and the found explanations didn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your query returns exactly one row, you want just one `INTO` clause.  You don't put the `INTO` clause in your projection (the list of columns you are selecting).  You also can't specify lengths on parameters just the data type.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getFlightDetails
(ticketNumberIn IN integer, fullName OUT varchar2, flightNumberOut OUT integer, 
 route OUT varchar2, durationInHours OUT number) 
IS
BEGIN
  select    
    pe.FirstName || ' ' || pe.LastName,
    fl.FlightNumber,
    fl.DepartureAirport || ' - ' || fl.ArrivalAirport,
    ROUND((fl.ArrivalDate - fl.DepartureDate)*24,1)
  into fullName, 
       flightNumberOut, 
       route, 
       durationInHours
  from Purchase pu
    inner join Person pe on pe.SSN = pu.SSN
    inner join Ticket ti on ti.TicketNumber = pu.TicketNumber
    inner join Flight fl on fl.FlightNumber = ti.FlightNumber
  where pu.TicketNumber = ticketNumberIn;
END;
```

Not related to your issue, I would suggest coming up with a naming convention for your parameters that differentiates them from column names and is used consistently.  Having one parameter whose name is `Out` but not doing the same thing on all the other `OUT` parameters will likely be confusing.  Personally, I'd just use a `p_` prefix for parameters

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getFlightDetails
(p_ticketNumberIn IN integer, 
 p_fullName OUT varchar2, 
 p_flightNumber OUT integer, 
 p_route OUT varchar2, 
 p_durationInHours OUT number)
```

If you wanted to have `pin_` and `pout_` to differentiate `in` and `out` parameters, that wouldn't be unreasonable.

Comment: Thank you! It works just fine. I also followed your advice and changed the name of the parameters.